# keyup event on input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

In my code, both chrome and jsfiddle, find no errors, but while running it, it doesn't alerts anything.

my code is:
**js:**

```
$("input#photoimg").on('keyup', function () {
    alert('key up');
});
```

**html:**

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="photoimg">
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58nxY/1/

Answer (score 2):

For file inputs, use the change event:

```
$("input#photoimg").on('change', function () {
    alert('file added/changed');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/58nxY/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But can you explain why? If keyup doesn't work with inputs, on what it does?

Comment: `keyup` does work on inputs, just not reliably on file inputs which have a **lot** of security restrictions on them.

Answer (score 0):

Keyup just work for text input but in file and documents handling you need "change" event to be fired.